# Wordpress Prevent Auto Formating Not Working

Tags: wordpress

I have tried to get WordPress 3.7.1 to stop autoformating:

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
```

but it's not working! What am I doing wrong?

** **Edit** **

Added in functions.php;

Using Custom Theme using Bootstrap 3.0.2

**Plugins Active:**

- All-in-One Event Calendar by Timely
- Business Directory Plugin
- Business Directory Plugin - Google Maps Module
- Display widgets
- Gravity Forms
- Ultimate TinyMCE
- Widgetkit
- WooCommerce
- WP Editor
  WYSIWYG Widgets

Chad

Comment: remove_filter() is the accepted solution for disabling wpautop.  We need a little more information your situation to answer this, specifically Where did you put the code? functions.php in your theme? a custom plugin? A Drop-in?

Answer (score 0):

Create a page template file.  In your template file, add:

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
```

to your page template file (e.g., my_template.php), in the line ABOVE this line:

```
<?php the_content(); ?>
```